# Ubuntu shell curly brace expansion - confusion with sox command

Tags: files, rename, xargs

I'd like to search through multiple subdirectories and convert all .mp3 files to .al files. Here's how I do it:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -t -r -I {} sox {} -r 8000 -c1 -e a-law {}.al lowpass 4000 compand 0.02,0.05 -60,-60,-30,-10,-20,-8,-5,-8,-2,-8 -8 -7 0.05
```

But this leaves me with the files as filename.mp3.al, so then I do this:

```
rename 's/.mp3.al$/.al/' ./**/*.mp3.al
```

Seems a bit cack-handed, but I can't figure how to get that expansion to remove the old .mp3 extension.

(In case anyone is wondering, this is for use on an Asterisk 13.8.2 PBX system. I'm aware it has it's own built-in converter, and can also play mp3s, but neither solution is as good as going native alaw!)

Comment: seems to me that you'd need to pass find's output to a small shell script that would rearrange the filename as arguments to sox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, in this context the `{}` aren't really "shell curly braces" (in the sense of *brace expansion* for example), they're just textual placeholders for arguments. As such you could pass them into a shell command and use the shell's parameter substitution facility to modify the names, like

```
sh -c 'for f; do somecommand "$f" "${f%.*}.al"; done' sh {}
```

To illustrate with a simpler command, given

```
$ tree
.
├── dir
│   ├── other file.mp3
│   └── some file.csv
├── other file.txt
└── some file.mp3

1 directory, 4 files
```

Then

```
$ find . -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'for f; do printf "%s --> %s\n" "$f" "${f%.*}.al"; done' sh {}
./dir/other file.mp3 --> ./dir/other file.al
./some file.mp3 --> ./some file.al
```

or (if your system's `find` supports it)

```
$ find . -name '*.mp3' -exec sh -c 'for f; do printf "%s --> %s\n" "$f" "${f%.*}.al"; done' sh {} +
./dir/other file.mp3 --> ./dir/other file.al
./some file.mp3 --> ./some file.al
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to rate the answer but it won't show until I get more rep. Here's what I ended up with, working perfectly thanks to your examples! `find . -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'for f; do sox "$f" -r 8000 -c1 -e a-law "${f%.*}.al" lowpass 4000 compand 0.02,0.05 -60,-60,-30,-10,-20,-8,-5,-8,-2,-8 -8 -7 0.05; done' sh {}`